# Rx table view not being reloaded after the datasource gets updated

Tags: ios, uitableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa, rxdatasources

I have a table view that I am trying to make reactive. I have it working using Swift.

Following is the RxSwift code

```
viewModel.getDetailMessages().asObservable().bind(to: messageTableView.rx.items){ tableView, row, element in
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
            print("The size is", InboxData.sharedInstance.inboxdata[messageIndexPath.row].messageDetail.count)
            print("The size is element", element)
            if !element.isSender{
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recieverCell", for: indexPath) as! RecieverMessageTableViewCell
                cell.message.text = element.messageText
                cell.message.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 287
                cell.message.layer.cornerRadius = 8
                cell.message.layer.masksToBounds = true
                return cell
            }else{
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "senderCell", for: indexPath) as! SenderMessageTableViewCell
                cell.senderMessage.text = element.messageText
                cell.senderMessage.layer.cornerRadius = 8
                cell.senderMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 287
                cell.senderMessage.layer.masksToBounds = true
                return cell
            }
        }
```

Following is my view model

```
class MessagwViewModel{

    func getDetailMessages() -> Observable<[Message]> {
        return Observable.just(InboxData.sharedInstance.inboxdata[messageIndexPath.row].messageDetail)
    }

}
```

And this is the message data class

```
class MessageData {

    static let sharedInstance = MessageData()

    var message1 = Message(profilePicture: "Taylor Ward", artistName: "Taylor Ward", messageText: "Hi How are you?", isSender: true)

    var messages = [Message]()

    private init() {
        loadMessages()
    }

    func loadMessages() {
        messages.removeAll()
        messages.append(message1)

    }

}
```

On Click of a button I am trying to append data to the Message array as follows

```
sendButton.rx.tap.bind{ value in
            InboxData.sharedInstance.inboxdata[messageIndexPath.row].messageDetail.append(Message(profilePicture: "", artistName: "", messageText: self.messageTextView.text, isSender: true))

       self.messageTableView.reloadData()
            self.messageTableView?.scrollToBottom()
            print("Button clicked")
        }
```

The count of the array increases every time I append a new element . But the table view does not reload even though the data source has the latest value

Can anyone one point out what the problem is? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the `MessagwViewModel`. Observable.just only streams out one element and then completes. It doesn't monitor the object for changes. This simplest fix (i.e. hack) is to make `messageDetail` a `Variable`. You don't show how that variable is defined, but based on how it is called, I assume it is currently like this: `var messageDetail: [Message]`. Change it to `let messageDetail: Variable<[Message]>`. Assign to it by using `messageDetail.value = ...` and read from it through its Observable `messageDetail.asObservable()`

Comment: Variable has been deprecated, use BehaviorRelay instead.

Comment: Better still would be to avoid using either Variable or BehaviorRelay.